# Addition of single bits in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I have been trying to code a combinational circuit that adds single bits. When I am simulating my code I am getting unknown values ("U") from my temporary registers. I am adding my code for reference. If I am missing something or my logic is wrong please correct me.

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity serial_adder is
    Port ( a : in std_logic;
           b : in std_logic;
           c : in std_logic;
           d : in std_logic;
           e : in std_logic;
           f : in std_logic;
           g : in std_logic;
           h : in std_logic;
           sum : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0));
end serial_adder;

architecture Behavioral of serial_adder is
    signal temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4 : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    signal temp5, temp6, temp9 : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    signal temp7, temp8 :std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
begin
    process (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
    begin
        temp1(0) <= a or b;
        temp2(0) <= c or d;
        temp3(0) <= e or f;
        temp4(0) <= g or h;
        temp7 <= temp1 or temp2;
        temp8 <= temp3 or temp4;
        temp9 <= temp5 or temp6;

        if (a = b and temp1(0) /= a) then
            temp1(1) <= not temp1(0);
        else
            temp1(1) <= '0';
        end if;
    
        if (c = d and temp2(0) /= c) then
            temp2(1) <= not temp2(0);
        else
            temp2(1) <= '0';
        end if;

        if (e = f and temp3(0) /= e) then
            temp3(1) <= not temp3(0);
        else
            temp3(1) <= '0';
        end if;
    
        if (g = h and temp4(0) /= g) then
            temp4(1) <= not temp4(0);
        else
            temp4(1) <='0';
        end if;
    
        if (temp1(1) = temp2(1) and temp7(1) /= temp1(1)) then
            temp5 <= ('1' ,temp7(1), temp7(0));
        end if;
     
        if (temp3(1) = temp4(1) and temp8 (1) /= temp3(1)) then
            temp6 <= ('1' ,temp8(1), temp8(0));
        end if;   
     
        if (temp5(2) = temp6(2) and temp9(2) /= temp5(2)) then
            sum <= ('1', temp9(2), temp9(1), temp9(0));
        end if;
    
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

[image]

Comment: What does your simulation do?

Comment: I am getting U as the result, all the temp signals are showing value U. I have added an image of my simulation.

Comment: Signals do not update until the process suspends.   If you need a data object that updates immediately after an assignment, you need a variable.

Comment: But variables outside the process should be shared right?

Comment: You have only one process and no other concurrent statements. What outside? Note while temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8 and temp9 are evaluated in your process none of them are in the process sensitivity list. Adding those won't help, you also have [logic problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCP1L.jpg).

Comment: I don't get what your code should do, but I'll give it a try to initialize the temp signals with (others => '0').

Comment: My code is to add 8 single bits and obtain a result.

Comment: "If I am missing something or my logic is wrong please correct me."  That's too broad and implies too much work on the part of your readers.  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." Reducing  terms and converting them to logical expressions is a lot of work, which also points out could rely on synthesis and count '1's in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The signals are all 'U' because the process is never accessed.

According to your sensitivity list, the process is only executed on the input signals

```
process (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
```

With this in mind, none of those signals had a change in value for the process to be completed.

Within your testbench try to change the input value of one of the signals and the process should be executed changing the values of your output.

Comment: I changed my sensitivity list. I added all the temp signals in the list and after computing the sum, I assigned it to the sum outside the process block. But still, it shows some problem

Comment: @user15725054 What does "some problem" mean? Please edit your question (there is a small link below the question), adding the changed source, and showing the exact problem. Or, if it is not connected to the issue, please post a new question.

Comment: Use `process (all)` and simulate/compile for VHDL-2008. Sensitivity lists have been deprecated in VHDL since 2008.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.3 Process statement "If the process sensitivity list is specified using the reserved word **all**, then the sensitivity list of the wait statement is constructed by taking the union of the sets constructed from each of the statements in the process by applying the following rules..."  Not deprecated at all and there can be valid reasons to manually specify the sensitivity list. Every process executes at least once, invalidating this answer. A sensitivity list implies a wait statement as the last statement with a sensitivity clause (10.2 Wait statement).

Comment: Sorry I had to write an answer, I do not have enough reputation for commenting on other's posts... Are you able to post an image of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the process when you don't use any clocks inside the process. Usually (at least in my experience) you either use a process with a clock (and mostly a reset if case) OR you use combinatory logic, which you do outside a process.

In an FPGA, the logic in a process is only "executed"/"analyzed" when a signal in the sensitivity list changes. On the other hand, VHDL code outside the process is implemented with logic gates (i.e. no clocked flip-flops, but and/or/... gates and so on) and thus is updated constantly and almost instantly.
If you use processes and forget signals in the sensitivity list or use weird VHDL code in the process that doesn't allow proper synthetization with FPGA logic (i.e. a process without a clock like in your example), it might work in the simulator but not in the FPGA.

That being said, I would recommend to either convert your problem into a clocked process:

```vhdl
    architecture Behavioral of serial_adder is
        -- define signals...
    begin
        process (clk)
        begin
            if rising_edge(clk) then
                if reset = '1' then
                    -- reset signal to their default level:
                    temp1(0) <= '0';
                    -- ...
                    
                else
                    -- here goes your main code:
                    temp1(0) <= a or b
                    -- ...
                    if (a = b and temp1(0) /= a) then
                        temp1(1) <= not temp1(0);
                    else
                        temp1(1) <= '0';
                    end if;
                    -- ...

                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
    end Behavioral;
```

...or use pure logic, i.e. replace if-else with when-else ([what is the difference](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73387/difference-between-if-else-and-case-statement-in-vhdl))

```vhdl
architecture Behavioral of serial_adder is
    -- define signals...
begin
    temp1(0) <= a or b;
    -- ...
    
    temp1(1) <= not temp1(0)    when ((a = b) and (temp1(0) /= a))
           else '0';
    -- ...
    
end Behavioral;
```